# Google Scripts getFiles(), what order is returned?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

When you call [`<folder>.getFiles()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfiles) in a Google Script, does the [`FileIterator`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator) returned have a particular ordering? It seems like it the most recently modified file might come first, but I don't see this documented.

Comment: Don't depend on it. If you need a particular order, use the Drive API via the Advanced Service (aka the REST API). You can order your results there.

Comment: For example, using Drive API of Advanced Google Service, when ``Drive.Files.list({orderBy: "modifiedDate desc"})`` is run, the elements of the result is the descending order. So the most recently modified file can be retrieved as the 1st element. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list